# Why is there no native string folding in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm building an application to read from a SQL database into Pandas for analysis.  The data is 'medium data' - too big for one computer (8GB RAM) to hold in memory.  I really didn't want the cost and hassle of spinning up AWS instances constantly and getting beefier hardware was difficult (I work in non profit), so I looked to optimize my own data read memory cost.

I've spent a long time implementing this solution from mobify: http://www.mobify.com/blog/sqlalchemy-memory-magic/

Specifically method 3: they use a dictionary that stores all unique string values.  This avoids duplication of objects holding the same string value, by instead passing a reference to the same string.  I took their code and implemented it and the results have been very impressive (reduction of memory use by 2-10x, depending on data slice).

It was straightforward enough that I'm confused as to why Pandas doesn't have this natively. I'm a noob to the world of Pandas, but it seems like duplication of strings within large datasets is a given these day.  Is there any drawback to a default string folding in the DataFrames?  Am I missing something here?

**TL;DR** Weakness of pandas is the high memory cost.  String folding seems like a straightforward way to significantly reduce the memory overhead.  Why doesn't it have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas does have something similar built-in in the form of categoricals. They probably only work well for relatively small numbers of unique strings, but they do save on memory usage by mapping each unique string to a numeric code and then storing those codes, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'strs': [random.choice(['banana', 'pineapple', 'orange']) for i in range(100000)]})
df['catted'] = pd.Categorical(df['strs'])

df.memory_usage()
Out[10]: 
strs      800000
catted    100024
dtype: int64
```

Comment: canonical way to convert is .astype('category') on a Series

Comment: cool!  didn't realize that.  but why isn't it natively implemented in the read_sql()?

Comment: @AZhao categoricals are more restrictive than strings in some ways, e.g. you can't just append more rows if those rows contain previously unseen strings. You should only convert to categorical if you know the restrictions don't matter for your current use case, so it has to be done explicitly. I'm not sure if the solution you posted would have the same drawbacks, I suspect it would.